# Automatically initialize IOptions<T> in constructor

Tags: c#

Simplification of the Dependency Inversion (Injection via ctor) syntax is not applicable to C# 9. Was planned for C# 10, but even from that #10 was recently moved away...
Source: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2691

We were supposed to change this:

```
public class MyManager    
{  
    private readonly ILogger<MyManager> _logger;  
    private readonly MyService _myService;  
  
    public MyManager(ILogger<MyManager> logger, 
                     MyService myService)  
    {  
         _logger = logger;  
         _myService = myService;  
    }  
}
```

To this:

```
public class MyManager    
{     
    public MyManager(ILogger<MyManager> _logger, 
                     MyService _myService)  
    { }  
}
```

> How can we cover the `IOptions<MySettings>` case with this simplification also ?

```
public class MyManager    
{     
    private readonly MySettings _mySettings;

    public MyManager(ILogger<MyManager> _logger, 
                     MyService _myService,
                     IOptions<MySettings> mySettings)  
    {
        _mySettings = mySettings.Value;
    }  
}
```

It doesn't work ok by applying the same pattern of simplification

```
public class MyManager    
{     
    // private readonly MySettings _mySettings; // remove it to simplify DI

    public MyManager(ILogger<MyManager> _logger, 
                     MyService _myService,
                     IOptions<MySettings> _mySettings)  
    { }  
}
```

because `_mySettings` should be an `MySettings` type, and not an `IOptions<MySettings>` type.

Note: By applying the same pattern implicitly we can admit that `_mySettings` won't be a `MySettings` type, but an `IOptions<MySettings>`. But to use in code something like `_mySettings.Value.SpeficSettingField` is weird.

[C# digest -> this week's favorite -> C# Coding Guidelines & Practices](https://csharpdigest.net/digests/351)

Comment: What you're saying about C# 9 is incorrect. Perhaps you're getting confused by records?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt - I've seen that published on C# digest, under "this week's favorite" topic (pardon publishing source name... at least I won't paste an URL to the source to avoid violating StackOverflow rules). I've performed a search on Microsoft docs to see any documentation, but, didn't succeed (maybe it's to raw/early) :)

Comment: It doesn't exist, and isn't in the pipeline :-). I would know - I'm one of the community ambassadors for the C# language design team. I'll try and find the article...

Comment: I know typescript supports the syntax, and was happy to see the info in the article mentioned above. To experiment this I quickly updated a ctor in the controller of my solution and have seen VS syntax checker does not complain. However, the compilation still doesn't work at all. Meanwhile, I've performed a search to inspect how to use IOptions<T> also, but because didn't found anything I have asked the community... But, someone from community seems to be surprisingly upset :) :(  I don't see anything wrong in the question. If the feature is still not applicable, maybe we'll have it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer really. It's too early for the feature :)
As @Yair mentioned: **That's still not applicable to C# 9.**

I've found the url to the docs: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2691
According to it: **Was planned for 10.0 Candidate in Language Version Planning, but unfortunately was removed from it on 6 February 2021 (probably for a later version)**

For now I am going to mark the question as resolved, but will come with a proper answer later, when we'll have fun with `PrimaryContructors` - that's how we will call them.
Thanks for tolerance